# Center image in row with floated element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with `bootstrap 3` and want to center a logo on a page, but also include a button to its right. The logo should center across the page, and disregard the button's width.

I have achieved this with `JS` but i want a pure `CSS` solution. I am using `LESS` if this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var logo = $('.logo img');
  var pdfBtn = $('#pdf-button');
  var win = $(window);

  var alignlogo = function() {
    var pdfBtnWidth = pdfBtn.outerWidth();
    logo.css({
      'position': 'relative',
      'left': pdfBtnWidth / 2
    })
  };

  win.on('load resize orientationchange', alignlogo);
});
```

```css
.transaction-head {
  text-align: center;
}
.transaction-head-logo {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  @media screen and (min-width: @screen-sm) {
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 75px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="transaction-head">
  <div class="top-block clearfix">
    <a id="pdf-button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="/url/to/generate/pdf" target="_new">
                Download PDF
            </a>
    <div class="logo">
      <img class="transaction-head-logo" src="url/to/logo">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can following apply css on your logo to make it in center horizontally and without being affected by button width:

```
.logo {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%:
}
```

```css
.transaction-head {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.transaction-head .logo {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: @screen-sm) {
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="transaction-head">
    <div class="top-block clearfix">
        <a id="pdf-button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="/url/to/generate/pdf" target="_new">
            Download PDF
        </a>
        <div class="logo">
            <img class="transaction-head-logo" src="url/to/logo">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TheRealPapa buxie / búxiè :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `'left': pdfBtnWidth / 2` from js code its unnecessary if you want the image in center because its giving `left:50px` to image which is totally no use.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var logo = $('.logo img');
  var pdfBtn = $('#pdf-button');
  var win = $(window);

  var alignlogo = function() {
    var pdfBtnWidth = pdfBtn.outerWidth();
    logo.css({
      'position': 'relative',
      //'left': pdfBtnWidth / 2
    })
  };

  win.on('load resize orientationchange', alignlogo);
});
```

```css
.transaction-head {
  text-align: center;
}
.transaction-head-logo {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  @media screen and (min-width: @screen-sm) {
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 75px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="transaction-head">
  <div class="top-block clearfix">
    <a id="pdf-button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="/url/to/generate/pdf" target="_new">
                Download PDF
            </a>
    <div class="logo">
      <img class="transaction-head-logo" src="url/to/logo">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```